# position absolute to center in the middle of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello guys i am having trouble to center a div in the middle of the screen after setting the position to absolute , i dont want to use flexbox because of the browser compatibilities

```
<style>div{
height:200px;
width: 300px;
display:inline-block;
position: absolute;
background-color:red;
}
</style>
<div>
some content
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqWYQg

Comment: `margin-left: -150px;` if the width always going to be `300px`

Comment: transform: translateX(-50%); Add this line in your code with browser compatibility.

Comment: flexbox is [pretty well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) - 97% with vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 4):

Add `left:50%` and `top:50%` plus `transform:translate(-50%, -50%)`.

This will center an element horizontally and vertically. This is also useful for responsive designing as the element will stay centered even if you resize the browser

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  some content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Absolute Horizontal And Vertical Centering](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_profile_view_base_recent_activity_details_shares%3B10lOjYZ2TfC3eyeERjTQkw%3D%3D), which is cross browser (works in IE8), and pretty simple:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  some content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `left: 50%;`, `top: 50%;` and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`.
Don't forget to use the prefixes to cross browser compatibility.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  some content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
    height:200px;
    width: 300px;
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:red;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%); 
    }
```

```html
<div>
some content
</div>
```

Use other browser's compatibility